# create visual studio c++ project to run under winre

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

my visual studio win32 c++ projects don't interact with the desktop when running on winre ( the recovery environment installed onto a usb stick from the 'create recovery drive' within windows ). any idea why console apps dont send their output to the command line window, and why GUI apps dont show a window on the desktop ? i have tried win32console and win32 windowed applications from visual studio 2008 and visual studio 2019, on various winre environments from older and latest win10pro installations, and a recent win11pro installation. i'm sure i have got a project to work once in the past but cant remember what was different. the projects have all been created with default options with no ATL or MFC enabled.

Answer (score 0):

changing Project Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library from Multi-threaded DLL to Multi-threaded, enables the project to interact with the WinRE desktop.

while this setting is documented on the microsoft website, i failed to appreciate it needs to be changed for all permutations of debug/release/x32/x64 projects and so was inadvertently compiling with DLL linking enabled when i thought i had turned it off.